# How to change socket.io connection url?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I connecting to server this way:

```
function initSockets() {
  socket = io.connect(connectionUrl, {
    reconnection: true,
    reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
    reconnectionDelay: 1000
  });
}
```

I need to change connectionUrl. (I want to give this option to users)
So, I make this:

```
socket.disconnect();
connectionUrl = newConnectionUrl;
initSockets();
```

The problem is when user give a wrong address and socket.io can't connect to it, then socket.io invokes infinite reconnecting. Even if user gave another address and connect to it, then socket.io still reconnecting and there is a lot of weird things hapening.

Comment: handle the disconnect, reconnect_attempt and error events with *some code* which calls disconnect method, then it will stop and you can show a message etc.

Comment: Your socket.io server determines what the proper URL is to use for connecting and the client MUST use the URL that the server has pre-determined.  You can't just have clients making up URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to update the Manager uri attribute:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("https://my-domain-a.com");

socket.io.uri = "https://my-domain-b.com";

// force reconnection
socket.disconnect().connect();
```

Answer source: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/discussions/4246#discussioncomment-1952661